# Disable monitor output to save power

Tags: ubuntu, display

I am running a single board computer (Intel Atom based) off a battery, with Ubuntu 18.04 as the OS, to do some remote monitoring and processing.

Aim is to get the system to run for 72 hours which I have done.

However, I have noted that though there is no monitor connected, with monitor output enabled an extra 0.1A is drawn.
Disabling monitor output using a `xset dpms force off` command or `xrandr --output HDMI-I --off` saves me my 0.1A.
However, whilst both commands work fine when issued from an application running in a terminal, they don't work when the application autostarts on boot up (I am using cron to fire up the application on boot using `@reboot python3 /bin/bootapp.py &`).

Application is Python and the commands to switch are issued using os.system(`xset dpms force off`) or os.system(`xrandr --output HDMI-I --off`).
I note that the application is up and running well before Ubuntu finishes booting so thinking that Ubuntu might be overriding the command I also issue it 5 minutes after boot up.
But still, the monitor output is enabled.

How do you disable the monitor output? I could usefully do with the extra 0.1A.

Comment: walloftextishardtoread

Comment: @Mark Jordan, the formatting of text requires two spaces before a hard return to end a paragraph. Editing tips are at https://superuser.com/editing-help#code .

Answer (score 0):

The `DISPLAY`-variable is not set for a daemon. `xset`-command won't know which display to target. On an interactive shell session, the variable is set on login.

Suggestion: use `-display` argument to specify.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I solved it by adding a bash script, to disable the monitor, into startup applications, though this needed a short delay (I used 20 seconds) to guarantee the monitor was disabled.